# psycopg2.errors.IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have next error log

```
     ERROR - 2020-04-22 09:32:38,508 - sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool: Exception during reset or similar
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 693, in _finalize_fairy
         fairy._reset(pool)
       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 880, in _reset
         pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 538, in do_rollback
         dbapi_connection.rollback()
     psycopg2.errors.IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
     SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

Any ideas of the reason and how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you give more details about yout setup? Is it a web app? Where is it hosted? Is the PostgreSQL server remote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I my case i had leek of sessions with was not closed properly.

I have rewrite all code with constructions like

```
    session = init_session()
    try:
        ... # business logic with other calls and raise-s
        session.commit() # optional
    finally:
        session.close()
```

And the problem is gone

Comment: Do you recall how you discovered that the leaking of sessions was the problem? Like was there a diagnostic or logging or something that led you to that conclusion?

Comment: by checking number of open session at db 
for example select count(*)  from pg_stat_activity

Comment: Isn't `commit()` enough because that will close the transaction but keep the connection alive. Is it necessary to `close()` the session?

Answer (score 5):

The root cause is that you have database sessions that have started a transaction with BEGIN but are inactive longer than the PostgreSQL parameter idle_in_transaction_session_timeout (defined at PG instance level):

```
  idle_in_transaction_session_timeout (integer)

   Terminate any session with an open transaction that has been idle for longer than the specified duration in milliseconds. This allows
   any locks held by that session to be released and the connection slot
   to be reused; it also allows tuples visible only to this transaction
   to be vacuumed. See Section 24.1 for more details about this.

   The default value of 0 disables this feature.
```

To fix this you need either to fix application code to not have idle transactions too long or to modify PG parameter idle_in_transaction_session_timeout.